# how to add axesLables to n3-charts

Tags: d3.js, angularjs-directive

I'm using n3-charts to display charts on a webpage based on angular.
Everything works fine but I can't find an easy way to add a label to the axis.
Have I missed something?
It is common to add something like the time unit or percentage etc to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an API option for this.  So here's a quick and ugly hack using `ng-init`:

```
$scope.onInit = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      var axis = d3.select(".x.axis");
      var width = axis.node().getBBox().width;
      axis.append("text")
        .text("X Axis Label")
        .attr("dy", 30)
        .attr("dx", width /2 )
        .attr("text-anchor","middle");

      axis = d3.select(".y.axis");
      var text = axis.append("text")
        .text("Y Axis Label");
      var tWidth = text.node().getComputedTextLength();
      text.attr("dy", 15 )
        .attr("dx", -tWidth )
        .attr("text-anchor","start")
        .attr("transform","rotate(-90)")
        .text("Y Axis Label");

    }, 100);
  };
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nzHWqM0F0uCCiLMqOlCI?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

Thanx Mark I refined your suggestion a bit so it works on a resize event and if I have two y axes.
My code ended up like this:

```
$scope.init = function(){
        //var svg = $("svg");
        //console.log("svg found "+svg);
        console.log("d3 found "+d3);
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.redrawAxisLabels();

}, 100);
        var window = angular.element($window);
        window.bind('resize',function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
            self.redrawAxisLabels();
            }, 100);
            console.log('resize');
        });

    };
    this.redrawAxisLabels = function(){
        self.appendXlabel();
        self.appendYlabel();
        self.appendY2label();
    },
    this.appendXlabel = function(){
        var axis = d3.select(".x.axis");
        var width = axis.node().getBBox().width;
        axis.append("text")
            .text("Time")
            .attr("dy", 30)
            .attr("dx", width /2 )
            .attr("text-anchor","middle");
    };
    this.appendYlabel = function(){
        var axis = d3.select(".y.axis");
        var text = axis.append("text")
            .text("FES");
        var tWidth = text.node().getComputedTextLength();
        text.attr("dy", 15 )
            .attr("dx", -tWidth )
            .attr("text-anchor","start")
            .attr("transform","rotate(-90)")
            .text("FES");
    };

    this.appendY2label = function(){
        var axis = d3.select(".y2.axis");
        var text = axis.append("text")
            .text("Fuel Consumption");
        var tWidth = text.node().getComputedTextLength();
        text.attr("dy", -15 )
            .attr("dx", -tWidth )
            .attr("text-anchor","start")
            .attr("transform","rotate(-90)")
            .text("Fuel Consumption");
    };
```